# Position the square on the left after it reaches the top

Tags: c++, opengl

```
#include <stdio.h> // this library is for standard input and output
#include "glut.h"// this library is for glut the OpenGL Utility Toolkit
#include <math.h>

float squareX = 0.0f;
float squareY = -0.3f;
float squareZ = 0.0f;

static int flag = 1;

void drawShape(void) {
    glTranslatef(squareX, squareY, squareZ);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(162, 50);
    glVertex2f(162, 10);
    glVertex2f(220, 10);
    glVertex2f(220, 50);
    glVertex2f(162, 50);
    glEnd();
}

void initRendering() {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

// called when the window is resized
void handleResize(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0f, (float)w, 0.0f, (float)h, -1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void drawScene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    drawShape();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// make the square go up
void update(int value) {
    if (flag) {
        squareY += 1.0f;
        if (squareY > 400.0) {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
}

// make the square go right
/* void update(int value) {
    if (flag) {
        squareX += 1.0f;
        if (squareX > 400.0) {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
} */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Moving Square");
    initRendering();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

I have uploaded this code before but this time I made the square go all the way up. The code just moves the square up, but I don't know how to position it on the left once it reaches the top, so then I can make it move to the right. I have uploaded a demonstration on how I want it to look below.

Preview:

[image: Square Move Up]

What I want it to do next:

[image: Square Move Right]

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What is working currently?

Comment: The square currently goes up, but I don't know how to make the square go to the left, so I can make it move all the way to the right then.

Comment: You will have to do a simple sort of collision detection ... using simple if statements to change its direction once it hits the  window border.

Comment: @Muddy so the second image, the one moving the square to the right was not generated by your program ? If that is your question, you should translate the image to the left before start moving it to right, so adjust your `squareX`

Comment: All my code does is move the square up. After it reaches the top, I want it to be positioned on the left so I can move it to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to initialize the variables `squareX`, `squareY` and `squareZ` with the start position of the rectangle:

```cpp
float squareX = 162.0f;
float squareY = 0.0f;
float squareZ = 0.0f;
```

Do not draw a rectangle specific position, but draw a rectangle on the position (0,0) with a length (`width`, `height`). Let the model matrix (set by [`glTranslatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml)), do the job of the positioning:

```cpp
void drawShape(void) 
{
    float width = 58.0f;
    float height = 40.0f;

    glTranslatef(squareX, squareY, squareZ);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(width, 0);
    glVertex2f(width, height);
    glVertex2f(0, height);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glEnd();
}
```

Use a variable `state`, which has stated the direction of the current movement:

```cpp
int state = 1; // 0: stop; 1: move up; 2: move right
```

If the rectangle a certain position has reached, then the `state` has to be changed and a the new start position can be set. At the final position, the rectangle can stop or the process can even be restarted:

```
void update(int value)
{
    if (state == 1) // 1 : move up
    {
        squareY += 1.0f;
        if (squareY > 400.0)
        {
            state = 2;
            squareX = 0.0f;
            squareY = 180.0f;
        }
    }
    else if (state == 2) // 2 : move right
    {
      squareX += 1.0f;
      if (squareX > 400.0)
      {
          state = 0;

          // restart
          //state = 1;
          //squareX = 162.0f;
          //squareY = 0.0f;
      }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
}
```